# UISlider subclass does not move beyond 0 - 1 range

Tags: ios, swift

I'm subclassing `UISlider` and overriding `maximumValue` to be 5, `minimumValue` to be 0, `isContinuous` to be `false`, and both track tint colors. Is there something I NEED to override to fix this issue, such as `draw`? I tried setting the slider directly to a value above 1, but it still doesn't go beyond it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

There's no exceptions, debugging it shows the value that is sent to `setValue` is changing accordingly, the only issue I'm seeing is that the slider isn't updating visually.

```
class Slider: UISlider {
    private var viewData: ViewData

    // MARK: - Initialization
    init(viewData: ViewData) {
        self.viewData = viewData
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        render(for: viewData)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.viewData = ViewData(orientation: .vertical, type: .discrete)
        super.init(frame: frame)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func render(for viewData: ViewData) {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc private func sliderValueDidChange(_ sender: UISlider) {
        self.setValue(sender.value, animated: true)
        Haptic.triggerImpact(.light)
    }

    // MARK: - Overrides
    override var maximumValue: Float {
        get {
            switch viewData.type {
            case .continuous: return 100
            case .discrete: return 5
            }
        }
        set { maximumValue = newValue }
    }

    override var minimumValue: Float {
        get { return 0 }
        set { minimumValue = newValue }
    }

    override var isContinuous: Bool {
        get {
            switch viewData.type {
            case .continuous: return true
            case .discrete: return false
            }
        }
        set { isContinuous = newValue }
    }

    override var minimumTrackTintColor: UIColor? {
        get { return .white }
        set { minimumTrackTintColor = newValue }
    }

    override var maximumTrackTintColor: UIColor? {
        get { return .gray }
        set { minimumTrackTintColor = newValue }
    }

    override open func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var newBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        newBounds.size = CGSize(width: 222, height: 10)
        return newBounds
    }

    override open func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect {
        var newThumb = super.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)
        newThumb.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        return newThumb
    }

    override open func setValue(_ value: Float, animated: Bool) {
        guard viewData.type == .discrete else {
            super.setValue(value, animated: animated)
            return
        }
        let roundedValue = Int(value)
        super.setValue(Float(roundedValue), animated: animated)
        setNeedsDisplay()
        Haptic.triggerImpact(.light)
    }
```

Comment: Every one of your overridden properties with `set` are invalid and cause infinite recursion.

Comment: @rmaddy huh. So I guess I'm better off just setting those values instead of overriding them. Thanks for the help! I'll accept your answer if you wanna submit one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your overridden properties are causing infinite recursion in the `set` blocks.

Instead of overriding them just to set a specific value, update your `render` method to set the desired initial values.

```
private func render(for viewData: ViewData) {
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)

    minimumValue = 0
    switch viewData.type {
    case .continuous: maximumValue = 100
    case .discrete: maximumValue = 5
    }

    isContinuous = viewData.type == .continuous
    minimumTrackTintColor = .white
    maximumTrackTintColor = .gray
}
```

Besides this update, remove those overridden properties and the slider will work just fine.